# how to make a python jumbler and un-jumbler

Tags: python, encryption

Hi so I was wandering how would I make a program in python that would jumble up a password I put into it then a secondary program that would un-jumble it?

Comment: That's a bad idea. If you can decrypt your stored passwords, then anybody can. Can you explain more why you want to "un-jumble" them? Is this just to check that the user has entered a valid password?

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply looking to obscure a string from a *casual observer*, you can use a cipher. For example, the [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) can encode and decode a string. If you want a cryptographic solution, you should use [PyCrypto](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/) or a similar existing library.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have the need for [asymmetric cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). You can utilize this by having one of your programs "jumble" up the password and encrypt it using the public key, and then have the secondary program "unjumble" it using the private key.